# bash extglob pattern matching breaks when enclosed in a function

Tags: bash, function, shopt, extglob

This works

```
shopt -s extglob
find /usr/!(^*|@*) -maxdepth 0 -cmin +1 -exec echo {} \;
shopt -u extglob
```

This returns an error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('

function test {
  shopt -s extglob
  find /usr/!(^*|@*) -maxdepth 0 -cmin +1 -exec echo {} \;
  shopt -u extglob
}

test
```

What am I missing, that would permit me to use this in a function?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is bash needs `extglob` to be turned on at two times:

1. when parsing the script
2. when executing the actual command

By including the `shopt` into the function body, 1. is not satisified. If you broaden the scope of the `shopt` to include the function declaration, too, bash will parse the function correctly, but it will fail when running it (i.e. 2. is not satisfied):

```sh
shopt -s extglob
function test {
    find /usr/!(^*|@*) -maxdepth 0 -cmin +1 -exec echo {} \;
}
shopt -u extglob
```

The error:

```
find: ‘/usr/!(^*|@*)’: No such file or directory
```

So, just turn `shopt extglob` on at the beginning of the script and that's it.
Or, if you really need it to be off elsewhere, turn it on and off both inside and outside the function:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
function test {
    shopt -s extglob
    find /usr/!(^*|@*) -maxdepth 0 -cmin +1 -exec echo {} \;
    shopt -u extglob
}
shopt -u extglob

test
```